# Switch screen in flutter without context in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this dart file(app_bar.dart) and am storing Appbars inside it and i have logged_home.dart file where am calling the app_bar.dart from. Now i want to be able to navigate to a new screen when i click next screen it sends me to `PostData()` while in app_bar.dart.

app_bar.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/screens/authenticate/login.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/screens/author/post_data.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/screens/home/unlogged_home.dart';

//for logged in user

final loggedBar = AppBar(
  title: Text('Kopalaz Dictionary'),
  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  elevation: 0.0,
  actions: <Widget>[
    FlatButton.icon(
        color: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PostData()));
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        label: Text(
          'Post',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        )),
  ],
);

//For unlogged users

final unloggedBar = AppBar(
  title: Text('Kopalaz Dictionary'),
  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  elevation: 0.0,
);
```

logged_home.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/screens/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/shared/app_bar.dart';

class LoggedInUserHome extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[10],
      appBar: loggedBar,
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text(
                'Kopalationary Menu',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Home'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Wrapper()));
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'My profile',
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Logout'),
              onTap: () async {
                dynamic result = await _auth.logoutUser();
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'About',
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Development in progress!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do not forget that in Flutter *everything is a widget* !

So my advice would be to create functions which returns a widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//for logged in user
AppBar loggedBar(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text('Kopalaz Dictionary'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      elevation: 0.0,
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton.icon(
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PostData()));
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            label: Text(
              'Post',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            )),
      ],
    );
}

//For unlogged users
AppBar unloggedBar(BuildContext context) {
  return AppBar(
    title: Text('Kopalaz Dictionary'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    elevation: 0.0,
  );
}
```

Do keep in mind that flutter does a lot in the background and it is therefore better practice not to store widget in global variable. If you need to access those widgets from different part of your app you should look into [Inherited Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) or other form of state management (see list [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)).

Comment: Right, to create an AppBar you need to implement PreferredSizeWidget. Therefore I think here the best option would be to creates functions which return your AppBars.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to validate the question if you fill it's the right solution :)

Answer (score 0):

see below link:

**Navigate without context in Flutter with a Navigation Service**

https://medium.com/flutter-community/navigate-without-context-in-flutter-with-a-navigation-service-e6d76e880c1c

also, you can use [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) library

Comment: how to pass multiple paramers and use them on on another next screen?

Comment: @Kamlesh The best new solution is use GetX library